# How can I add a shared library (set to use "isolated classloader") Websphere?

Tags: java, websphere, jax-ws

I have been getting some problems with my application because of library I used to JAX-WS. I found one solution but I have to add a share library in WAS 8.5 and I don't know how can I do it.

I'll leave you the link of the documentation I'm following.

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cxf-issues/201207.mbox/%3C310771353.90819.1343048795043.JavaMail.jiratomcat@issues-vm%3E

Answer (score 2):

Here's the documentation for managing shared libraries: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tcws_sharedlib.html

That document is for 8.5.5, but the procedure is the same on 7.0-9.0.

Quick summary: In the admin console, go to the "Environment" section, then "Shared libraries", then create one, name it whatever you want, and set the class path to either the specific jar files you need or the directory containing them (note that if you specify a directory, it'll pull in all the jars in that directory by default).  To use an isolated class loader, just check the "Use an isolated class loader" checkbox.